# New project with react native but errors

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

My head is so pain right now, I just screw up my old project and not able to run currently, So I guess I just create a new react native project and transfer my code to it, guess what? I hit this error after my creation of `react native` and ran react-native run-android.

```
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: dx.jar is missing

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.998 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

This `multidex` thing, I never set this before or anything previously on my 1st project like 1 week ago. With a new project, I can't even run my android emulator with react-native run-android for the 1st time.

Someone please help me to solve this issue please.

Comment: run your project from android studio then check logcat it will help.

Comment: i am new on this, any idea how do i run it on my studio?

Comment: @user1897151 Can you please add your app.gradle file here with your problem

Answer (score 3):

There are some common solutions for this issue. First of all you need to find your buildToolsVersion in gradle file. 
To import react native project into android studio follow these steps.

1. Open Android Studio and click **Open existing project**
2. Find your project folder and inside that there will be folder called **android**
3. Open that folder with android studio

Make sure you have the newest android studio release. 
If there is any build error just fix them simply by clicking the errors. 
Once you have correctly build your project find **`build.gradle (Module:app)`** file under Gradle Scripts.
There you can see the buildToolsVersion of your current project. Change it like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

After that clean your android project using **`Build > Clean Project`**  
Next rebuild your android project using **`Build > Rebuild Project`**

After that navigate your react native project folder and delete build folder.
It can be found here **`YourProject > android > app > build`** 
Then before you run your react native project, note that Android Emulator is already running. If not run your android emulator using android studio 
Finally run your react native project using **`react-native run-android`**